# an error has occurred see the log file eclipse .metadata.log

Tags: eclipse

I start eclipse luna with java 11 and have this  error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1hnn.png)

can you please help me?

Comment: We have no way of helping you without seeing what's in that log file.

Comment: Eclipse Luna is much too old to run with Java 11 you need to use the latest Eclipse SimRel 2018-09 (or 2018-12 which will released this month).